# Qt Mac assistant zsh: command not found: assistant

Tags: qt

I'm on macOS Catalina 10.15.6. I have installed `Qt 5.12.0` and can lunch Qt Creator.
But I can not lunch qt Assistant through the terminal.

```
assistant
zsh: command not found: assistant
```

However, the assistant should be included in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spotlight Search `assistant.app`
[image]